# Can't get the pandas dataframe output without index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

`signals` is a pandas dataframe where I store buy and sell signals. With the `getbuySignal` function, I can get on which date a buy signals has been generated, and store these date in `vector_buy` array. Then with the`get_close`function, I want to get the close price(from the`sh600004`dataframe) of the 20days before each 'buy day' and store them in `vector_close`.

I printed the`vector_close` to check whether my code is correct. But I got very odd output. The output for the `if i<20` part in the`get_close` function is an array contains only `close prices`. But the output for `else` part contains both `close prince` and `datetime index`. Like what shows in the picture at the bottom.

```
vector_buy = []
vector_close = []
def get_buySignal():
    list_buy = []
    for i in range(0, len(signals.index)):
        global vector_buy
        if signals['positions'][i]==1.0:
            list_buy.append(i)
            vector_buy = np.array(list_buy)
def get_close():
    close_list = []
    for i in vector_buy:
        global vector_close
        if i < 20:
            close_list.append(sh600004['close'][range(0,i)])
            vector_close = np.array(close_list)
            print vector_close
        else:
            close_list.append(sh600004['close'][range(i-19,i)])
            vector_close = np.array(close_list)
            print vector_close   

get_buySignals()
get_close()
```

Here's the output for`buy_vector`

```
array([  10,   37,   47,   57,   82,   94,  102,  148,  165,  179,  188,
    201,  248,  260,  270,  272,  290,  299,  331,  350,  361,  373,
    409,  417,  435,  449,  457,  465,  491,  511,  527,  536,  555,
    571,  592,  609,  634,  661,  672,  706,  718,  735,  776,  794,
    807,  838,  854,  870,  890,  907,  915,  934,  969, 1004, 1013,
   1020, 1032, 1034, 1039, 1050, 1099, 1116, 1140, 1157, 1202, 1214,
   1228, 1238, 1257, 1276, 1297, 1311, 1319, 1347, 1376, 1379, 1389,
   1406, 1425, 1455, 1460, 1478, 1492, 1518, 1533, 1545, 1559, 1574,
   1590, 1615, 1627, 1657, 1683, 1692, 1704, 1731, 1742, 1758, 1775,
   1795, 1824, 1836, 1852, 1864, 1905, 1913, 1950, 1966, 1986, 1999,
   2005, 2020, 2046, 2079, 2088, 2108, 2113, 2124, 2145, 2154, 2166,
   2178, 2218, 2234, 2244, 2251, 2302, 2309, 2311, 2324, 2339, 2351,
   2372, 2387, 2397, 2408, 2422, 2446, 2462])
```

[image]

Comment: This is quite unclear as to what the problem is - what exactly is that screenshot showing? It seems to have a least 2 things printed. What do you expect to happen? Your code and your description of what it is meant to do also don't seem to line up - but can help with that once figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: The first print output is what I get when I print the `vector_close` from the `if i<20`. The second print output is the output from `else` part of the `get_close` function. I want to get rid of the datetime index for the output.

Comment: Can you update your code to show how you get the 2 things printed? You currently only have one print statement in your loop.

Comment: I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could optimize your code and use the power of Pandas to solve your problem. If I got it right, you'd like to get all the Indizes of Signals where signal['positions']==1. So you should'nt use the for-loop but try this:

```
list_buy = signal[signal['positions'] == 1].index
```

converting this in an np.array is easy:

```
vector_buy = list_buy.as_matrix()
```

For getting the last 20 entries in vector_close, try something like this:

```
vector_close = sh600004['close'].tail(20)
```

or

```
vector_close = sh600004['close'].head(20)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. That's very helpful. The index for `signals` are pd.datetime index. So each element in `vector buy` is `numpy.datetime64`. I want to count how many working days between each element. I used the`np.busday_count((datetime.datetime.strptime(vector_buy[0], '%Y/%m/%d')),(datetime.datetime.strptime(vector_buy[i], '%Y/%m/%d')))` . But is says the `strptime` requires a `string` argument. I'm wondering can you help me with that too?

Comment: I would recommend to get familiar with the pandas.Datetimeindex: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimeindex

I'm pretty shure you can solve your task with pandas only. So it should be more comfortable to stick to the pandas-methods instead of mixing it with numpy.

Comment: numpy. np.busday_count(list_buy[0].index.to_datetime(), list_buy[i].index.to_datetime()) might work...